# How to find the average resolution of bunch of images , so that I can feed the dimensions into a CNN layer in tensorflow?

Tags: python, image, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, resolution

I am working on a binary image classifier in tensorflow. I want to specify the img_shape in a Conv2D layer. I would like to know if there is a way of finding the average shape of all images in the dataset.

It would help a lot.
Thanks

Comment: It depends if the dataset is a directory full of JPEGs, a Python list of PIL Images, or a Numpy array of Numpy arrays.

Comment: Its a directory of JPEGs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution using PIL library (I am using a directory of images)

```
import PIL
from PIL import Image

widths = []
heights = []

for img in os.listdir(""):
    img_path = os.path.join("") # Making image file path
    im = Image.open(img_path)
    widths.append(im.size[0])
    heights.append(im.size[1])

AVG_HEIGHT = round(sum(heights)/len(heights))
AVG_WIDTH = round(sum(widths)/len(widths))
```

Comment: Well done and thank you for sharing back with the community. You can accept your own answer and bag the points, btw.

Comment: Hello, I got the error: PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied

Answer (score 1):

For those who have trouble using the code above, try this one, it works like clockwork!

```
import os
import PIL
from PIL import Image

widths = []
heights = []

dir_path = r"write your file path in here" # Adding 'r' to make the string a raw string

for img_name in os.listdir(dir_path):
    if img_name.endswith(".jpg") or img_name.endswith(".png") or img_name.endswith(".jpeg") or img_name.endswith(".bmp"):
        img_path = os.path.join(dir_path, img_name) # Adding img_name to the path
        im = Image.open(img_path)
        widths.append(im.size[0])
        heights.append(im.size[1])

AVG_HEIGHT = round(sum(heights)/len(heights))
AVG_WIDTH = round(sum(widths)/len(widths))

print(f"Average Height: {AVG_HEIGHT}")
print(f"Average Width: {AVG_WIDTH}")
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33872280)